# link to automatically expanded treemenu text disables links in the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I found this topic: [How to link directly to an FAQ option expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188833/how-to-link-directly-to-an-faq-option-expanded) and used this script in my website:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('.expand_text').each(function() {
      $(this).css("display", "none");
   });
   $('.treenode').click(function() {
      $(this).next('.expand_text').slideToggle("fast")
      return false;
   });
   (function(hash){
      if (hash !== undefined && hash.substring(0,1) === "#") {
         $(hash).slideToggle("fast");
      }
   })(window.location.hash);
});
```

So now I can provide a link to a particular page which opens with one of the menu items automatically expanded. For example: http://drgiannopoulos.com/estheticdentistry.html#bleach It is in Greek, but its obvious that you can land on the page with the first menu item expanded. However, if you scroll down a bit you'll notice two three lettered underlined words (sorry again its Greek!). These are links and they don't work! You can right click and select "open in a new tab / window" which will work fine, but the simple left click has been rendered inactive. I think this has to do with the above mentioned script and since I am totally new to all this I would like your help.
Thanks